# Symfony assetic loading is very slow in dev, and need a solution to speed it up

Tags: performance, symfony, assetic

We're currently using assetic to load all our assets, which works fine. In the dev environment, it loads all the assets individually, but rather slowly. In production, it compiles all the assets into 1 file, so it's very speedy.

After doing some reading, I've found that switching `use_controller` (under `assetic`, in `config_dev.php`) to false speeds it up a bit; but then we're forced to run `assetic:dump or assetic:watch`.

Are there any other options? There has to be an easier way to speed this up. Is it possible to force it to compile all the files into 1 on dev, just like on prod?

Another option that someone on our team suggested, was to have an array with all the file names, and check if we're on dev or prod. If we're on dev, then just run through the array and build the script elements (instead of using assetic) - the problem I saw with this, is that we're managing a massive array, which seems like too much overhead for something that should be much easier to deal with.

Comment: What os do you use? I switched a long time ago from windows with XAMPP to Centos with LAMP and this is incredible faster. I don't want to work with windows anymore.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, with LAMP

Comment: But there has to be a way to turn off certain assetic features, but still load the files. Just seems like such a simple thing, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Ubuntu should be okay. You could think about loading the compiled file on the work that you do not want to develop anymore and additional compile one or a few files where work on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `assetic.debug` in config to false for having a single file like in production. But you have to use `assetic:dump`.

If you really need performance and want to use `use_controller`, try to upgrade to PHP7 if you don't. PHP7 will speed up your scripts.

Comment: Thanks - changing the debug to false really helped it. I am also using `assetic:watch` instead (running in the background); so I don't have to worry about running dump all the time.